# Вылетает приложение android

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

Суть приложения проста,есть `WebView` и через него выводятся пара страниц.
Пытался скрыть ActionBar после этого стал вылетать. Скрываю его таким способом.
**style.xml**

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

    </style>
```

Весь код

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView myBrowser;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myBrowser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.myBrowser);
        myBrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myBrowser.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        myBrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/mypage.html");

        int currentapiVersion= Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
            myBrowser.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        }
/*---------------------------------*/
        if(currentapiVersion>=19) {
            myBrowser.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE,null);
        }
        else{
            myBrowser.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE,null);

        }
    }
```

**manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.user.recept">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: лог ошибки пожалуйста предоставьте

Comment: Ошибок нет,просто черный экран,хотя если в `style.xml` ничего не прописывает,все работает

Comment: а манифест файл тогда

Comment: Обновил , теперь там манифест

Answer (score 1, accepted):

поробуйте так

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Заработало!Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
getActionBar().hide();
```

вставить в OnCreate()